# Why am I Getting a syntax error in my Cursor Loop?

Tags: sql, syntax

Can anyone explain why I am getting a syntax error in the EXEC statement below? If I change EXEC to PRINT the syntax looks perfect.

```
use BillingTracking

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @User varchar(100);
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select SqlUser from dbo.tbl_Users order by SqlUser
    
    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @USer

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC ('GRANT INSERT ON dbo.tbl_Audit TO ' + '[' + @User) + ']'
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @User 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

The error I'm getting is:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

I tried using the quotename function in several places but I still get the error.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: which DBMS is this ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because your brackets don't match up for the `exec` (near your `+` operators as the message says)

Comment: You arent closing the paranthesis on "EXEC ('GRANT IN....." You need to add a ")" on the end.

Comment: Thanks Johan. An obvious oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are working with MS SQL Server.
If that's correct, please use **||** for concatenation or *concat(var1,var2...)* itself.
Also use *execute* instead of *exec*.

So this should work:

```
use BillingTracking

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @User varchar(100);
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select SqlUser from dbo.tbl_Users order by SqlUser
    
    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @USer

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE ('GRANT INSERT ON dbo.tbl_Audit TO ' || '[' @User||']')
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @User 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

P.S. You also had misplaced "**)**". Main cause of your error was that error.